# Unable to resolve SinchClient and Call ,I had already added .aar file and required dependencies

Tags: android, voip, sinch, android-sinch-api

**I am unable to resolve SinchClient , I had already added its sdk .aar file and dependencies but it not showing please help me out in that
**Failed to resolve: :sinch-android-rtc:+

```
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/91851/OneDrive/Desktop/Android Development/Pop/app/build.gradle">app</a>****



implementation(name:'sinch-android-rtc', version:'+', ext:'aar')




dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add some more info about your problem, because right now we don't have enough context?

Comment: i had added details please check

Comment: Hi, is your libs directory at the same level as the build.grade file?

Comment: yes ,Roland its at same level.

Comment: Can you put the `implementation(name:'sinch-android-rtc', version:'+', ext:'aar')`
 inside `dependencies {}`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I had tried but it still showing error :(